# .htaccess rewrite get parameter inside the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having troubles to rewrite a get parameter inside the URL.

I need to replace to 0 the value or delete at all next request "filter=all" from urls across entire site.

Example of entire requst:
`mysite.com/?filter=all&search_text=&type=xx&pagination=10&search_page=10&cs_loc_max_input=300&cs_loc_incr_step=1&goe_location_enable=off&submit=`

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule   ^filter=0$   filter=all&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter=all$
RewriteRule ^filter=0$ ?filter=all&%{QUERY_STRING}[L,NC]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]|)filter=(all|all2)([&?].*|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?filter=0&%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,NC,L]
```

And few ways more, but nothing works as expected...  Please, need a help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the final URL you want to show in browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)filter=all(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1filter=0%2 [R=301,L]
```

If you try to rewrite without redirect. Use `[L]` instead of `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.